# Why can't I wear a hat?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2017

I get an error when I try to wear a hat, I tried many times but without any chance :

[image: can't wear a hat]

Comment: Should be all fixed now: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304373/grinched-winterbash-seems-to-have-gone-missing/304399#304399

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the entire Hat system is extremely slow at the moment, including the [Winter Bash homepage](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/). I suppose you can try again after the system is back in full function.

Comment: I.e. in 2018 Winter bash season ...

Comment: Maybe the server is plugged into the wrong UPS?

Comment: It seems a logic reason, now i can wear it :)

Comment: Needed defrosting